# SYSTEM tablespace growing over 64GB

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, tablespace

My Oracle database version is 12.1.0.2.0

The DB I'm talking about is used for purpose of creating "packages" (not oracle package, but a package that contains codes/scripts) that are deployed in UAT/Production, etc environments.
For this purpose, new schemas are created at runtime and old ones which are not used anymore are dropped periodically.

The tablespace in which these schemas are created/dropped is 84GB in size and there is over 50% free space available.

SYSTEM tablespace, which is of 64GB in size has only 10MB free.

All segments in SYSTEM tablespace are owned by either SYS or SYSTEM.

Top 15 rows of below query are:

```
SELECT owner, 
       segment_name,
       segment_type,
       bytes
  FROM dba_segments
 WHERE tablespace_name = 'SYSTEM'
 ORDER BY bytes desc;
```

[image: output of above query]

Does 64GB SYSTEM of tablespace sound right?
Can it be reduced, and if yes then how?

Comment: Count of records for tables:

Comment: SOURCE$ 116738579

Comment: IDL_UB1$ 627158

Comment: IDL_UB2$ 330314

Comment: ARGUMENT$ 5298051

Comment: If you connect as SYSTEM and run this query does it return rows? `select * from user_objects where oracle_maintained != 'Y'` (Assuming your tag is correct and you are running on 12c.)

Comment: 15 gigabytes of source code doesn't sound right.  Take a look at SYS.SOURCE$ - are there many extra copies of code in there?  But even if the code is not longer there, I'm not sure if there's anything you can do about it.  It looks like that table cannot be shrunk.  This might be a problem with no simple fix - just add some space.

Comment: @APC, output of query is 1.

Comment: POST_REFRESH_LOG

     20489          20489 TABLE                   06-FEB-19 06-FEB-19
2019-02-06:10:06:46 VALID   N N N          1

NONE            N

Answer (score 1):

SOURCE$ is any PLSQL source code (procedures, packages, types, etc etc).

Similarly, IDL_UBL1, I_SOURCE are related to the same.

Your addenda means you have 116 *million* lines of PLSQL in that database. That's a fair bit of code :-)

If you really genuinely need 116 million lines of source code, then I don't think a 64G SYSTEM tablespace is unreasonable.

C_OBJ# being large suggests you potentially have a lot of objects in your database. So take a look at DBA_OBJECTS as well for opportunities to clean up.

Comment: Since its SYSTEM tablespace, I'm not sure what to drop or what not to drop. Having read a few articles, I was warned to not drop anything from SYSTEM tablespace as it is the code used by Oracle. On DBA_OBJECTS, let me have a look and come back to you. Thanks.

Comment: There are 1771539 records in dba_objects. Out of these 13476 belong to SYS & 645 to SYSTEM. There are 285 users (which I mentioned earlier that are created on the fly and dropped periodically after few weeks), each having about 6k-7k objects. When a user is dropped, is there a cleanup required to free up space from C_OBJ#? or is it handled implicitly?

Comment: Never drop anything owned by SYS (or any other Oracle internal account) unless *you* inadvertently created it yourself. Free space will be reused by *other* objects are they are created or grow, but I don't think you will get that space *back*.

Comment: Is that to conclude that nothing can be done apart from adding space?

Comment: If you *need* those 116 million lines of code, then yes, you need that space. If you do *not* need those lines of code, then drop the offending PLSQL objects and that space will be available for new/replacement code. But you wont get that space back unless you export/import the entire database